# How to use customize message Bar in outlook vsto programmatically?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I am using form region and custom task pane but I can't position them where message bar is displayed in reading pane and inspector window 
[image]

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: ok can I control form region to show it for a specific email item other wise hidden

Comment: Yes, but use a task pane instead of a form region.

Comment: task pane not satisfying the UI needs that's y using a form region

Comment: Well, that's not an option.